# InvalidIdentityToken: Couldn't retrieve verification key from your identity provider

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am new to aws and kubectl, I need to deploy one of the app to aws. After deploying to eks cluster, I edited the ingress in the kubectl but unfortunately it returned 404 not found. (i am pretty sure the new service container works fine)

after checking from kubectl describe ingress, here are some events reports:

```
  Warning  FailedBuildModel  40m  ingress  Failed build model due to WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials
caused by: InvalidIdentityToken: Couldn't retrieve verification key from your identity provider,  please reference AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity documentation for requirements
           status code: 400, request id: xxxxxxxx-4a93-4e27-9d6b-xxxxxxxx
  Warning  FailedBuildModel  22m  ingress  Failed build model due to WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials
caused by: InvalidIdentityToken: Couldn't retrieve verification key from your identity provider,  please reference AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity documentation for requirements
           status code: 400, request id: xxxxxxxx-5368-41e1-8a4d-xxxxxxxx
  Warning  FailedBuildModel  5m8s  ingress  Failed build model due to WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials
caused by: InvalidIdentityToken: Couldn't retrieve verification key from your identity provider,  please reference AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity documentation for requirements
  status code: 400, request id: xxxxxxxx-20ea-4bd0-b1cb-xxxxxxxx
```

Anyone has ideas about this issue?

Comment: Hi angusovo welcome to SO. No one can possibly help you with the little information you've provided. That error usually indicates that (as the error message so clearly states) the [OIDC Provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html) is misconfigured to not provide AWS with a JWK it can use to verify the JWT the Pod is presenting to AWS

Answer (score 0):

My issue was caused by an OIDC misconfiguration, but I will be more specific in the hopes of helping anyone else:

- Ensure you have a discovery document in `.well-known/openid-configuration`
- Ensure you have a keys document in `.well-known/jwks.json`.
- Ensure the discovery document points to the correct URL for the keys document. (this was my issue)
- Ensure the files are publicly accessible.
- Ensure they keys document matches your Kubernetes cluster keys.

For example:

`curl https://my.oidc.provider.example/.well-known/openid-configuration | jq .jwks_uri`  should work, and return `https://my.oidc.provider.example/.well-known/jwks.json`.

`curl https://my.oidc.provider.example/.well-known/jwks.json` should work, and return a keys document.

You can get the keys document for your cluster by running `kubectl get --raw /openid/v1/jwks`.

Answer (score -3):

That error usually indicates that (as the error message so clearly states) the OIDC Provider is misconfigured not to provide AWS with a JWK it can use to verify the JWT the Pod is presenting to AWS.

This is the correct hint that will likely lead you to the answer, but its in a comment and people searching wont find it